# boost asio async_receive completion handler getting called with 0 bytes_transferred with out any error

Tags: boost, boost-asio

I am debugging a boost asio unix domain protocol client, after i issue async_receive , the completion handler gets called infinitely with 0 bytes_transferred, there are no errors passed to the completion handler. the error code is success.

Comment: i am using boost-1.55 version is this a bug or what ?

Comment: @RavikumarTulugu How big are the odds? Do you have a SSCCE, please?

Comment: (for context: [Select Isn't Broken](http://pragmatictips.com/26) and [It's Always Your Fault](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html))

Comment: @RavikumarTulugu: Yes, it's a bug. It's a bug in your code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit may be, i am not denying it, i am just investigating and asking for help what are the cases in which this might happen. in case the other end closes the connection the error should be end_of_file but in my case there is no error either.

Comment: @RavikumarTulugu: It would be inefficient for me to go and produce every possible combination of broken code using boost.asio, then list all the failure cases. Please do this the other way around, by posting your [testcase](http://sscce.org); since you've already been debugging with it for the last few days, it should just be a matter of copy/pasting those <50 lines! :)  _[Lounge: well that was predictable]_

Comment: If you downgrade to 1.53, does the issue go away? Perhaps it's [this one](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/asio-Incorrect-reporting-of-bytes-transferred-in-write-handler-in-1-54-td4649588.html).

Comment: ...oh, you're on unix - then ignore my previous comment please.

Comment: yes i am on Linux to be specific. i am in the process of downgrading and checking will update if any things turn different.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i got the problem nailed , i am posting the answer here , just incase some body else might very likely run into the same problem.

The completion handler falls into infinite loop if the boost::asio::buffer passed to the async_receive function is of length 0. In my case i was passing a vector of size 0.